# What is data("dataset") in R good for?

Tags: r

The help page of the *data* function says that it can be used to load a dataset. It seems however that all datasets defined in packages are already available whether *data* is called or not. Example:

```
> libary(MASS)
> names(quine)
[1] "Eth"  "Sex"  "Age"  "Lrn"  "Days"
> data("quine")
> names(quine)
[1] "Eth"  "Sex"  "Age"  "Lrn"  "Days"
```

Even datasets in unloaded packages are available without call of *data*:

```
> names(boot::acme)
[1] "month"  "market" "acme"
```

So what is *data("dataset")* good for and when is it necessary?

Comment: What about loading classical datasets not necessarily available in packages. `data("Titanic")`

Comment: *Titanic* is in package *datasets* and is available without calling `data("Titanic").`

Comment: `all datasets defined in packages are already available whether data is called or not` that's not at all true, it's completely up to the package authors if this works or not

Comment: @rawr Can you please elaborate in an answer what the packages are doing for making it available?

Comment: @cdalitz https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L21

Comment: @rawr According to the documentation https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data, `LazyData` does not affect the visibility of data, but that it is loaded "on demand", i.e., only when first accessed.

Comment: for `lazydata: false` data sets will not be available via `::` or `:::` or by simply typing the name even if the package is in your search path. for packages like this, you use`data()` to make them available

Comment: @rawr Thanks for the explanation. I have added it as an answer, because this seems to be the only case when `data()` is strictly needed.

Answer (score 4):

There are cases that's it's not needed, cases that it's useful and cases that is required.

1. For those cases that we don't have any conflict of names (object, other package's dataset or even functions) it's not really needed to load a dataset with `data`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

diamonds
## A tibble: 53,940 x 10
#   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
# 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
# 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
# 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
# 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
# 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
# 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
# 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
# 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
# … with 53,930 more rows
```

2. For those cases that it's useful, we can use it just for code readability, convention, by having some information about it, or even to assign it to a new environment.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds, verbose = TRUE, envir = e <- new.env())

#name=diamonds:  NOT found in names() of Rdata.rds, i.e.,
#   gss_cat

#name=diamonds:  NOT found in names() of Rdata.rds, i.e.,
#   fruit,sentences,words

#name=diamonds:  NOT found in names() of Rdata.rds, i.e.,
#   band_instruments,band_instruments2,band_members,starwars,storms

#name=diamonds:  NOT found in names() of Rdata.rds, i.e., 
#billboard,construction,fish_encounters,population,relig_income,smiths,tab 
#le1,table2,table3,table4a,table4b,table5,us_rent_income,who,world_bank_pop

#name=diamonds:  found in Rdata.rds
```

3. And finally, for those cases that it's required is when we have objects with the same name and we can't call the dataset without function `data`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

diamonds <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
diamonds
#[1] 1 2 3 4

data(diamonds)
diamonds

## A tibble: 53,940 x 10
#   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
# 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
# 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
# 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
# 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
# 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
# 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
# 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
# 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
# … with 53,930 more rows
```

Comment: The last case is an example for namespace pollution. The overwritten variable should still be accessible by explicitly providing the namespace, i.e., `ggplot::diamonds`.

Comment: That's true. However if you type again `diamonds` it'll display the object (`1, 2, 3, 4`) instead of the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments under the question, there was a case given when `data(dataset)` is strictly needed: when a package does not use the option `LazyData: Yes`.

If it is *yes*, the dataset is already visible and will be automatically loaded when first accessed. Otherwise it must be loaded with `data()`. "Lazy loading" was introduced to avoid unnecessary memory consumption of datasets coming with packages, while at the same time removing the need to use `data()`.